# Where the command client.stats comes from in Python driver?

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm following MongoDB university course M220, on using Python with MongoDB.

It starts with defining the connection:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
uri = "mongodb+srv://m220student:m220password@mflix.abcde.mongodb.net"
client = MongoClient(uri)
```

And then it uses `client.stats`
That gives:

```
Database(MongoClient(host=['mflix-shard-00-01.abcde.mongodb.net:27017', 'mflix-shard-00-00.9go7j.mongodb.net:27017', 'mflix-shard-00-02.9go7j.mongodb.net:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True, authsource='admin', replicaset='atlas-js08eu-shard-0', ssl=True), 'stats')
```

I can't figure out where the `stats` comes from?

There is nothing in MongoDB API documentation. I even unpacked and searched the source code wheel file and couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created an instance of the mongo db client, thus you have access to the `db.stats()` method:

Here's the documentation for that method:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.stats/